# If Larry, Moe and Curly visit a town with 7 churches

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am working through the following question:

> If Larry, Moe and Curly visit a town with 7 churches, then (a) in how many ways can all three visit the same church, and (b) in how many ways will they not all choose the same church?

For a) I have the following calculation:

$$\binom{7}{1} = 7$$

Is it that simple or am I missing something?

For b) I have this:

$$P_3^7 = 210$$

Am I on the right path, or have I made any errors? Thanks for your help!

Comment: a)  Yep.  Right.  And for b), just realize that the number of ways they will not all choose the same church is the *total number of ways they can go to church* minus the number of ways they all go to the same church.  Easy!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you! That clears things up!

Comment: Larry, Moe, and Curly were all Jewish (http://archive.jns.org/latest-articles/2012/12/3/the-jewish-side-of-the-three-stooges.html), so they were probably visiting synagogues rather than churches. Anyway, the answers depend on whether or not Larry visiting a given house of worship followed by Moe is considered different from Moe visiting first, followed by Larry, and so on.

Comment: Your answer on b) actually answers **another** question: "in how many ways can they all choose a different church to visit?"